# sync the bookmarks in Favorites folder with a computer

Tags: ipad, windows, ios

I can only sync the bookmarks in the Bookmark folder on my iPad. Is there a way to sync the bookmarks in the Favorite folder too ?

I am syncing between iPad and Google chrome(Desktop)

EDIT: Here is a picture that explains it all.

[image]

Comment: Do you use Safari or Chrome on your iPad ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I Safari. Because the Favourite section is only in Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the bookmarks. They were already synced but apple has decided to put them in the main bookmarks bar inside Chrome. Not in the "Safari Menu bookmark"